# NSString with different font sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

Is there a easy way to create the labels text with different font sizes without using `NSMutableAttributedString`?

```
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.03f %.03f", var1, var2];
//                                        ^
//                                        this value should be shown a little larger than the second value
```

Comment: nope. what's wrong with NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a something very easy once. I might mix that up with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can achieve the look you want by creating three labels, each of a different size. It use to be hard to get the baselines to line up, but if you use the auto layout constraint system, you can get all three labels to hug each other and also have the same baseline.

Comment: Hello David H, thanks for your suggestion (without down voting!). I actually thought about it but was still curious to find another solution within the label.text definition. I like easy approaches I finally took your advice and it looks pretty good. Thanks and good luck!